# How To Set Textview value to EditText

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

How can I set the Activity1 textview value to Activity2 edittext when I click the button?

Activity1

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override  
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);  
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("p",textview);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
    }  
});
```

Activity2

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
EditText.setText(bundle.getString("p"));
```

Comment: you are right way you just need to create EditText Object first

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about minimal understanding of problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
bundle.putString("p",textview);
```

to

```
bundle.putString("p",textview.getText());
```

and

```
EditText.setText(bundle.getString("p"));
```

to

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText)
editText.setText(bundle.getString("p"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the text, not the view itself:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);  
intent.putExtra("p", textview.getText());
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement your `Activity1` like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);  
intent.putExtra("p", textview.getText());
startActivity(intent);
```

Implement your `Activity2` like

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.balance);
          Editext dt=(EditText)findViewByid(R.id.edittext);
          Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
         dt.setText(bundle.getString("p"));
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Activity1

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override  
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);  
        intent.putExtra("p",textview.getText());
        startActivity(intent);
    }  
});
```

Activity2

```
Intent intent = getIntent;

EditText eidtText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
editText.setText(intent.getString("p"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following to your project

**Activity1**

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override  
public void onClick(View v) 
{
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);  
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("p",textview.getText().toString());
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
}  
                });
```

**Activity2**

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_editText)
editText.setText(bundle.getString("p"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below :

In your **Activity 1**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);  
intent .putString("p",textview.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

In your **Activity 2**

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId);
String bundle = this.getIntent().getString("p");
editText.setText(bundle);
```